# What is String Format C# {0,12:N0} (colon and commas) means?

Tags: c#

Okay here's the code example:

```
 string header = String.Format("{0,-12}{1,8}{2,12}{1,8}{2,12}{3,14}\n",
                                "City", "Year", "Population", "Change (%)");
  Console.WriteLine(header);
  string output;      
  foreach (var city in cities) {
     output = String.Format("{0,-12}{1,8:yyyy}{2,12:N0}{3,8:yyyy}{4,12:N0}{5,14:P1}",
                            city.Item1, city.Item2, city.Item3, city.Item4, city.Item5,
                            (city.Item5 - city.Item3)/ (double)city.Item3);
     Console.WriteLine(output);
  }
 }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//    City            Year  Population    Year  Population    Change (%)
//    
//    Los Angeles     1940   1,504,277    1950   1,970,358        31.0 %
//    New York        1940   7,454,995    1950   7,891,957         5.9 %
//    Chicago         1940   3,396,808    1950   3,620,962         6.6 %
//    Detroit         1940   1,623,452    1950   1,849,568        13.9 %
```

i understand about the colon after the args {0:N0} means no decimal, but what about the comas? like {0,-12}, and {1,12} what does comma means after the argument of the string format?

Comment: If only there was [some kind of documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Ian : oh thanks! i only found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) lol. thanks, i don't really get it when i read doc of msdn itself since the example is not that much.

Comment: Spend time learning how to navigate the MSDN pages.  I personally found it took some getting used to that they separate the class from the various members/methods, but once you get used to them they are fantastic.

Comment: @Ian : oh okay thanks for the suggestion, i always surf through their page though , if only i couldn't get any clear answer i will ask it here. thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MSDN Documentation is your friend (the link I gave in comments above wasn't the best either):
[Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Each format item takes the following form and consists of the following components:
>   {index[,alignment][:formatString]}

So the `index` is obviously the index of the provided arguments:

```
String.Format("Second argument = {1}, first argument = {0}", arg1, arg2);
```

`Alignment` specifies the desired width of the field and horizontal alignment:

> The formatted data in the field is right-aligned if alignment is positive and left-aligned if alignment is negative.

```
String.Format("{0,-12}" +    // first argument, left align, 12 character wide column
              "{1,8:yyyy}" + // second argument, right align, 8 character wide column,
                             // formatted as a year
              "{2,12:N0}" +  // third argument, right align, 12 character wide column,
                             // formatted as a number, 0 decimal places
```

And `formatString` you already know about (e.g. [The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 5):

They are *index component* and *alignment* component which is part of [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Here is composite formatting syntax;

```
{index[,alignment][:formatString]}
```

In your cases, `{0,-12}` and `{1,12}`, `0` and `1` are index component which is pointing your first 2 elements that you want to format. And `-12` and `12` are alignment components. They can be negative or positive values.

Positive values indicate alignment to the right and negative values indicate alignment to the left.

If you wanna use alignment component, you *have to* separate it from the index component **by a comma**. Colon (`:`) separates alignment component with `formatString` as you can see on syntax.

Since you use `{0,-12}` for `"Los Angeles"` (which is `11` character), it will be aligned with one (`12 - 11`) white space character to the left.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0, -12}{1}", "Los Angeles", "1940"); // prints "Los Angeles 1940"
```

but `Chicago` (which is `7` character), it will be aligned five (`12 - 7`) white space character to the left as;

```
Console.WriteLine("{0, -12}{1}", "Chicago", "1940"); // prints "Chicago     1940"
```

For positive values;

```
Console.WriteLine("{0, 12}{1}", "Los Angeles", "1940"); // prints " Los Angeles1940"
```

but

```
Console.WriteLine("{0, 12}{1}", "Chicago", "1940"); // prints "     Chicago1940"
```

Answer (score 1):

[The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#NFormatString)

> The numeric ("N") format specifier converts a number to a string of
> the form "-d,ddd,ddd.ddd…", where "-" indicates a negative number
> symbol if required, "d" indicates a digit (0-9), "," indicates a group
> separator, and "." indicates a decimal point symbol. The precision
> specifier indicates the desired number of digits after the decimal
> point. If the precision specifier is omitted, the number of decimal
> places is defined by the current NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits
> property.
>
> The result string is affected by the formatting information
> of the current NumberFormatInfo object. The following table lists the
> NumberFormatInfo properties that control the formatting of the result
> string.

For N0 the actual output will no contains digits after the decimal point (like in integer values).

[Align numbers with spaces](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/)

> To align float number to the right use comma „,“ option before the
> colon. Type comma followed by a number of spaces, e.g. „0,10:0.0“
> (this can be used only in String.Format method, not in double.ToString
> method). To align numbers to the left use negative number of spaces.

Comment: so why does {0,-12} and {2,12} doesn't show any difference on their appereance?