# C# Combo_box changes formatted string

Tags: c#, string, xaml, combobox, format

Given:

```
String course = String.Format
(
    "{0}-{2} {1}  {3} {4} {5}", 
    c.course_ID.ToString().Trim(), 
    c.course_Name.Trim().PadRight(20), 
    c.Section_Num.ToString().Trim(),
    c.Start_Time.ToString().Trim(), 
    c.Quarter.Trim(), 
    c.Year.ToString().Trim()) 
);
```

I have this output:

`"150-2 FF Test               11:59:00 Winter 2016"`

`"314-1 Test Course           11:59:00 Winter 2016"`

However, when these are then added to a combobox, the second line is always two spaces longer than the previous line.

```
combo_box.Items.add(course);
```

`"150-2 FF Test               11:59:00 Winter 2016"`

`"314-1 Test Course             11:59:00 Winter 2016"`

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: it is because of string length.

Comment: Can you explain?   Are you saying the end result string length is too long?

Comment: you need to calculate string length before PadRight(number based on your string length)

Comment: String length will always be less than 20.  Unless I read the docs wrong, PadRight should Pad the string so total length is now 20.   Also, it is padding correctly in the actual string.  After I call  combo_box.Items.add(string) is where it breaks.

Comment: Can you show the code that adds it to the combo box?  You could also see if String.Format works any better, I recently wrote [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34941255) showing how to use it for exactly this.

Comment: String.format (without pads) worked exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is one of font widths.  The default font for a Combo box is MS Sans Serif, which is a *variable-width* (or proportional) font.  Each character takes up a different amount of space.
[image: Fixed width vs variable width fonts]

Switching to a *monospaced* (or fixed-width) font such as Courier New should solve your problem:
[image: Changing font property on combobox]

Like so:
[image: Combobox with fixed-width font]

Comment: This solved it thank you.  The font spacing wasn't even on my radar.