# C# Can't find any information about this string format : {0:ji}

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I have some code to maintain and I saw a lot of traces using this string format: `ji`. For example:

```
LogManager.Debug("GetSomething" + "param: {0:ji}", someUserDefinedObject);
```

I don't remember to have seen this before and I cannot find it on MSDN. Someone knows what this format string does? Also: Any link to a *complete* reference on that subject ?

Many thanks!

--

**Note : Possible duplicates?** Didn't see any. Please, read the questions thoroughly and be sure to understand the subject before seeking for duplicates. If you find one, just close the question. Thanks.

Comment: Quick Google search turns up "Composite formatting". I've never used it though, so I won't answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940355/what-is-string-format-c-sharp-0-12n0-colon-and-comas and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If the object implements [`IFormattable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable(v=vs.110).aspx) then "ji" will be passed as the format, so it depends on what `someUserDefinedObject` is.

Comment: LogManager is a third party class? It is possible that such format could be specific to the library which know how to interpret them and output the final string based on it.

Comment: Is this not maybe a defect/bug. `j` and `i` sound suspiciously like lazily named loop variables

Comment: @juharr: well, I think you got it right! someUserDefinedObject is IFormattable. Didn't saw this. I will dig there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that whatever `someUserDefinedObject` is implements `IFormattable` and uses that format string.  Without seeing the code for the `ToString(String, IFormatProvider)` method we cannot say exactly what it does.  But here's an example showing how that works.

Given class defined as follows

```
public class Test : IFormattable
{
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return format;
    }
}
```

Then the following

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:hello}", new Test());
```

Will print

> hello

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It is exactly what you described.